# simple hash merge by array of keys and values in ruby (with perl example)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, variable-assignment

In Perl to perform a hash update based on arrays of keys and values I can do something like:

```
@hash{'key1','key2','key3'} = ('val1','val2','val3');
```

In Ruby I could do something similar in a more complicated way:

```
hash.merge!(Hash[ *[['key1','key2','key3'],['val1','val2','val3']].transpose ])
```

OK but I doubt the effectivity of such procedure.

Now I would like to do a more complex assignment in a single line.

Perl example:

```
(@hash{'key1','key2','key3'}, $key4) = &some_function();
```

I have no idea if such a thing is possible in some simple Ruby way. Any hints?

For the Perl impaired, `@hash{'key1','key2','key3'} = ('a', 'b', 'c')` is a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) and is a shorthand for something like this:

```
$hash{'key1'} = 'a';
$hash{'key2'} = 'b';
$hash{'key3'} = 'c';
```

Comment: the problem is that `hash{'key1','key2','key3'}` is a wrong syntax. So you can't do that

Comment: What is that last Perl line? Invoking a function and updating the hash with the first three return values from the function and setting a local variable to the fourth (and more?) values?

Comment: @Phrogz: That's a hash slice, see the second code block [in here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Comment: @fl00r the `@hash{'key1','key2','key3'} = (1, 2, 3);` is perfectly correct in Perl.

Comment: The last line is in Perl, not Ruby. I think that &some_function returns array of values, for example: [1,2,3,4]. First three are saved to hash so it looks like this: @hash = { 'key1' => 1, 'key2' => 2, 'key3 => 3 }. Fourth value is stored in $key4. If &some_function returned more than 4 values, $key4 would stored array = [4,5,...]. (Sorry for mixing Ruby and Perl syntax :).)

Comment: I am talking about Ruby syntax :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine `[]=` to support this:

```
class Hash
  def []=(*args)
    *keys, vals = args # if this doesn't work in your version of ruby, use "keys, vals = args[0...-1], args.last"
    merge! Hash[keys.zip(vals.respond_to?(:each) ? vals : [vals])]
  end
end
```

Now use

```
myhash[:key1, :key2, :key3] = :val1, :val2, :val3
# or
myhash[:key1, :key2, :key3] = some_method_returning_three_values
# or even
*myhash[:key1, :key2, :key3], local_var = some_method_returning_four_values
```

Comment: Or, in the case where the OP wants to capture one of the return values as a local variable, you'd instead write `*h[:a, :b, :c], d = many_values`. However, monkeypatching all of Hash like that is wholly irresponsible and very likely to break other's code. This should be done as a module used to extend any Hash instance this would be done to.

Comment: @Phrogz: That is actually it. But I need to redefine `[]=` method of the `Hash` class which is not to my liking as well.

Comment: I would think you could also define a new method, called `Hash#multi=` for example, then use `*h.multi(:a, :b), c = many_values`. But I can't get this to work. @Phrogz, do you know of a way to do this?

Comment: Also, @Phrogz: this retains the original `h[k]=v` functionality, so how would it break other code?

Comment: @jtbandes `h[ [1,2] ] = 3 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for 3:Fixnum`. I use hashes with composite keys all the time.

Comment: @Phrogz: That was just a mistake in my code (it couldn't handle single arguments); try it now.

Comment: @jtbandes Now I'm getting contrived, but: `h[[1,2]] = [3,4]`.

Comment: @Phrogz: Fair enough, I guess it's impossible to preserve the original functionality without checking the number of arguments passed in. Which is probably actually a good idea. I just wish there were a way to make a custom operator that worked the same way as `[]=`.

Comment: OK this is probably the best answer. I could redefine `[]=` method of the `Hash` class with the parameter count checking as refered by @jtbandes. As there is probably no other simple enough solution I will rather stick with two line solution to store the function output in an array and merge it into the hash afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.9 `Hash.[]` can take as its argument an array of two-valued arrays (in addition to the old behavior of a flat list of alternative key/value arguments). So it's relatively simple to do:

```
mash.merge!( Hash[ keys.zip(values) ] )
```

I do not know perl, so I'm not sure what your final "more complex assignment" is trying to do. Can you explain in words—or with the sample input and output—what you are trying to achieve?

**Edit**: based on the discussion in @fl00r's answer, you can do this:

```
def f(n)
  # return n arguments
  (1..n).to_a
end

h = {}
keys = [:a,:b,:c]
*vals, last = f(4)
h.merge!( Hash[ keys.zip(vals) ] )
p vals, last, h
#=> [1, 2, 3]
#=> 4
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

The code `*a, b = some_array` will assign the last element to `b` and create `a` as an array of the other values. This syntax requires Ruby 1.9. If you require 1.8 compatibility, you can do:

```
vals = f(4)
last = vals.pop
h.merge!( Hash[ *keys.zip(vals).flatten ] )
```

Comment: I will try to explain the second Perl example:
I expect that `&some_function()` returns array of four values.
The complex Perl assignment example would assign first value of the return array in place of `key1` value of the `hash`, second value of the return array in place of `key2` value of the `hash`,... and finally the fourth value of the return array into `key4` variable.

Comment: The real problem here is that Perl will interpret multiple hash keys as independent `lvalue` targets whereas Ruby will consider them collectively an Array. For the most part, Perl has much more powerful yet subtle ways of expressing `lvalues` than Ruby does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There is no _simple_ one-line solution in Ruby that does what that Perl code does. The closest is what @fl00r has posted. In 11 years coding in Ruby, I don't think I've ever needed to extract a subset of return values from a method and update a hash with them while preserving other return values. I'm interested; do you have a use case where this useful (or necessary)?

Comment: @geronime See my update; it's not a single line, but it is one way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Phrogz: I coded several years in Perl and now almost a year in Ruby. I used a hash slice assignment many times. One example of that complex assignment could be this one (virtual mixed Ruby/Perl code): `@counters{'done','failed'}, queue_length = @redis.exec`, where `@redis.exec` returns values of queued commands `@redis.mget 'done', 'failed'` and `@redis.llen 'queue'` in one atomic transaction. In ruby I have to store the counters in an array and map it into hash later.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
def some_method
  # some code that return this:
  [{:key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :key3 => 3}, 145]
end

hash, key = some_method
puts hash
#=> {:key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :key3 => 3}
puts key
#=> 145
```

**UPD**

In Ruby you can do "parallel assignment", but you can't use hashes like you do in Perl (`hash{:a, :b, :c)`). But you can try this:

```
hash[:key1], hash[:key2], hash[:key3], key4 = some_method
```

where `some_method` returns an Array with 4 elements.

Comment: That is not a solution. What if I would like to use a result of some third-party method on the right side? Write some wrapper? Probably not.

Comment: @geronime check out my update. Method on the right side should return an Array with same number of items as on he left side

Comment: @floor: right, that could be done but it is unusable if I would like to pass the keys to be updated via an array with more than three elements. Like `@keys = ('key1','key2',... lots more); @hash{@keys} = &some_function()` in Perl.

Comment: If you want to capture extra return values as an array, change `key4` to `*key4`. Otherwise additional values will be ignored, and `key4` will always be exactly the fourth return value (or more accurately, the fourth element in the single array returned from the method).

Comment: @Phrogz: I know, Perl behaves similarly (all redundant values would be ignored - to store them in an array I just need to change the `$key4` scalar to `@key4` array).